# TabLayout scroll without a recyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using the new material design libraries:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

And I have the typical simple layout (3 tabs) as in the [cheesquareapp](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)

[image: Cheesesquare app image]

Here each tab fragment is a simple `RecyclerView`

layout - fragment_cheese_list.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And it works great.
But what I would like is to change the layout **fragment_cheese_list.xml** to have other items.
Such as this for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_list_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No results, tap button to search again"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see here, I would like to only show the `RecyclerView` when there are items, and if there are no items, I hide it to show the button and text.
I do this by switching visibilities (`View.GONE` - `View.VISIBLE`).

I have all of this done already, the problem is that when `RecyclerView` is NOT visible, I cannot "scroll" the layout to hide/show the toolbar like the last image in this picture

[image: Picture toolbar hidden]

So this brings a lot of problems, like if I switch from one tab to this one, while having the toolbar completely hidden, then I cannot show the toolbar again, unless I switch tabs and scroll to show it.

Thanks

**EDIT**: Maybe there is a way to programatically code that when the viewpager changes, hide/show with animation the toolbar. Although this is not the best solution it could be a workaround, if anyone knows anything about this please post how to code it (tried some code which did not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need wrap your button & label with [NestedScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_list_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No results, tap button to search again"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:visibility="gone"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @klifa, sorry I was mistyped. So does my solution help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Even if we don't use Recyclerview. Still we can scroll the screen. We need to do small modification in Cheesesquare.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView  
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_top"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_top"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/item1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
       >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/item2"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/item3"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/item4"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
       >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/item5"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="100dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top">

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ok"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

You need to put your layout in NestedScrollView. Set this to your fragment. Add that fragment.

You will see below result

[image: Tab1]

[image: Tab after scroll]

This might help you.